# How to add columns based on startand end time?

Tags: mysql, sql-server, database, time, split

I have two tables one has sports interval time and another has sports details.

Now I need to duplicate rows based on time interval from sports interval time.

**tbl_sport**

```
+----------+------------+----------------------------+
| sport_id | sport_name | minimum_slot_duration_time |
+----------+------------+----------------------------+
|        1 | Badminton  |                         60 |
|        2 | Basketball |                         30 |
+----------+------------+----------------------------+
```

**tbl_court**

```
    +----------+------------------+----------+------------+------------+
    | court_id |    court_name    | sport_id | start_time |  end_time  |
    +----------+------------------+----------+------------+------------+
    |        1 | Badmiton court   |        1 | 1453269600 | 1453276800 |
    |        2 | Basketball court |        2 | 1453397400 | 1453410000 |
    +----------+------------------+----------+------------+------------+
```

**Expected output:**

```
+----------+------------------+----------+------------+----------+
| court_id |    court_name    | sport_id | start_time | end_time |
+----------+------------------+----------+------------+----------+
|        1 | Badmiton court   |        1 | 11:30      | 12:30    |
|        1 | Badmiton court   |        1 | 12:30      | 13:30    |
|        2 | Basketball court |        2 | 23:00      | 23:30    |
|        2 | Basketball court |        2 | 24:00      | 00:30    |
|        2 | Basketball court |        2 | 01:00      | 01:30    |
|        2 | Basketball court |        2 | 02:00      | 02:30    |
+----------+------------------+----------+------------+----------+
```

**My Try:**

```
SELECT
    court_id,
    court_name,
    sport_id,
    LEFT(CAST(FROM_UNIXTIME(`start_time`) AS TIME),5) AS start_time,
    LEFT(CAST(FROM_UNIXTIME(`end_time`) AS TIME),5) AS end_time
FROM
    tbl_court
INNER JOIN
    tbl_sport ON tbl_sport.sport_id = tbl_court.sport_id
```

Request to give me both MySQL and SQl-Server query's, Since i am new to MySQL but i have basics knowledge in MS.

Comment: Hi and welcome to SO!  This isn't a code writing service.  But we can help you when you get stuck.  Please have a go at this query yourself.  If it doesn't work show us what you tried and detail where it failed.  Follow these tips and you'll be more likely to recieve a helpful answer.

Comment: @destination-data hi and thanks for your kind reply , I have updated my question with my tried query.

Comment: You didnt explain what field type is `start_time`  also what is the logic to create `11:30-12:30`  why not `11:00-12:00` and why stop at 13:30??

Comment: How did the data get in the table in the first place?   Just reverse the logic that was used to turn "11:30" into "1453269600".

Comment: @JuanCarlosOropeza : it's timestamp field.

Comment: @TabAlleman : use sqlfiddle type this query `SELECT LEFT(CAST(FROM_UNIXTIME(1453269600) AS TIME),5) AS start_time`

Comment: Any helping hands ?? :( :(

Comment: I ask for clarification about how create the result you expect. Havent got any reply yet

Comment: and if you know sqlFiddle why didnt provide one?